# Find a value in an xml file and copy all related TAGS to a new xml with VBA

Tags: xml, vba

i have an xml and i'd like to search for a specific value and then copy all TAGS related to this value to another xml.

Here's an example of the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<FlussoMisure xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
CodFlusso="PDO"> 
 <IdentificativiFlusso> 
  <PIvaUtente>00000000000</PIvaUtente> 
  <PIvaDistributore>00000000000</PIvaDistributore> 
  <CodContrDisp>000000</CodContrDisp> 
 </IdentificativiFlusso>
<DatiPod>
  <Pod>IT001E00000001</Pod>
  <MeseAnno>08/2017</MeseAnno>
  <DatiPdp>
    <PuntoDispacciamento>NORD</PuntoDispacciamento>
    <Trattamento>O</Trattamento>
    <Tensione>15000</Tensione>
    <PotContrImp>200,000</PotContrImp>
    <PotDisp>200,000</PotDisp>
  </DatiPdp>
  <Curva>
    <Raccolta>P</Raccolta>
    <TipoDato>E</TipoDato>
    <Validato>S</Validato>
    <PotMax>96,264</PotMax>
    <Ea E1="1,590" E2="1,560">01</Ea>
    <Er E1="0,660" E2="0,660">31</Er>
  </Curva>
</DatiPod>
</DatiPod>
<DatiPod>
  <Pod>IT001E00000002</Pod>
  <MeseAnno>08/2017</MeseAnno>
  <DatiPdp>
    <PuntoDispacciamento>NORD</PuntoDispacciamento>
    <Trattamento>O</Trattamento>
    <Tensione>15000</Tensione>
    <PotContrImp>138,000</PotContrImp>
    <PotDisp>138,000</PotDisp>
  </DatiPdp>
  <Curva>
    <Raccolta>T</Raccolta>
    <TipoDato>E</TipoDato>
    <Validato>S</Validato>
    <PotMax>153,600</PotMax>
    <Ea E1="1,590" E2="1,560">01</Ea>
    <Er E1="0,660" E2="0,660">31</Er>
  </Curva>
</DatiPod>
</FlussoMisure>
```

What i'd like to do is searching for value contained in TAG Pod and generate an identical xml with only one record for that POD, here is the output i'd like to have searching for value "IT001E00000002":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<FlussoMisure xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" CodFlusso="PDO"> 
 <IdentificativiFlusso> 
  <PIvaUtente>00000000000</PIvaUtente> 
  <PIvaDistributore>00000000000</PIvaDistributore> 
  <CodContrDisp>000000</CodContrDisp> 
 </IdentificativiFlusso>
<DatiPod>
  <Pod>IT001E00000002</Pod>
  <MeseAnno>08/2017</MeseAnno>
  <DatiPdp>
    <PuntoDispacciamento>NORD</PuntoDispacciamento>
    <Trattamento>O</Trattamento>
    <Tensione>15000</Tensione>
    <PotContrImp>138,000</PotContrImp>
    <PotDisp>138,000</PotDisp>
  </DatiPdp>
  <Curva>
    <Raccolta>T</Raccolta>
    <TipoDato>E</TipoDato>
    <Validato>S</Validato>
    <PotMax>153,600</PotMax>
    <Ea E1="1,590" E2="1,560">01</Ea>
    <Er E1="0,660" E2="0,660">31</Er>
  </Curva>
</DatiPod>
</FlussoMisure>
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance,

Andrea

Comment: Please read about XPATH:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/288913/how-to-use-xpath-queries-in-msxml-dom-selectnodes-method

Comment: Hi Peakpeak, i read the info on the link you posted but i'm not able to apply them to what i need...i'm sorry but i'm a beginner...can you give me some other informations? Thanks in advance

Comment: XPath is not beginners stuff, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks anyway Peakpeak, i'll try to use xpath but if there's anybody who can help me, maybe with the starting part of the code, it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, consider XPath's sibling, [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), used to transform whole XML documents. Specifically, you can run the [Identity Transform](http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity) to remove all other `<DatiPod>` nodes that do not match the search criteria. In VBA, you can use the [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742(v=vs.85).aspx) library to run XSLT 1.0 scripts even build XSLT dynamically from string to pass in search item:

**VBA**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub XSLTransform()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    ' ENABLE REFERENCE: Microsoft XML v, #.#
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument, newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument

    ' LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
    xmlDoc.async = False
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\Input.xml"

    xslDoc.async = False
    xslDoc.LoadXML DynamicXSLT("IT001E00000002")  '<------ PASS SEARCH ITEM

    ' TRANSFORM XML
    xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save "C:\Path\To\Output.xml"

    MsgBox "Successfully transformed XML!", vbInformation
    Exit Sub

ExitHandle:
    Set xmldoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Err.Raise xslDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , xslDoc.parseError.reason
    Resume ExitHandle

End Sub

Function DynamicXSLT(searchpod As String) As String
    Dim xslstr As String

    xslstr = " <xsl:stylesheet version=""1.0"" xmlns:xsl=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"">" _
                & "   <xsl:output indent=""yes"" method=""xml"" encoding=""UTF-8"" />" _
                & "   <xsl:strip-space elements=""*""/>" _
                & " " _
                & "   <xsl:param name=""param1""/>" _
                & " " _
                & "   <xsl:template match=""@*|node()"">" _
                & "     <xsl:copy>" _
                & "       <xsl:apply-templates select=""@*|node()""/>" _
                & "     </xsl:copy>" _
                & "   </xsl:template>" _
                & " " _
                & "  <!-- REMOVE ALL OTEHR PODS -->" _
                & "   <xsl:template match=""DatiPod[Pod!='" & searchpod & "']"">" _
                & "   </xsl:template>" _
                & " " _
                & " </xsl:stylesheet>"

    DynamicXSLT = xslstr

End Function
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlussoMisure CodFlusso="PDO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <IdentificativiFlusso>
        <PIvaUtente>00000000000</PIvaUtente>
        <PIvaDistributore>00000000000</PIvaDistributore>
        <CodContrDisp>000000</CodContrDisp>
    </IdentificativiFlusso>
    <DatiPod>
        <Pod>IT001E00000002</Pod>
        <MeseAnno>08/2017</MeseAnno>
        <DatiPdp>
            <PuntoDispacciamento>NORD</PuntoDispacciamento>
            <Trattamento>O</Trattamento>
            <Tensione>15000</Tensione>
            <PotContrImp>138,000</PotContrImp>
            <PotDisp>138,000</PotDisp>
        </DatiPdp>
        <Curva>
            <Raccolta>T</Raccolta>
            <TipoDato>E</TipoDato>
            <Validato>S</Validato>
            <PotMax>153,600</PotMax>
            <Ea E1="1,590" E2="1,560">01</Ea>
            <Er E1="0,660" E2="0,660">31</Er>
        </Curva>
    </DatiPod>
</FlussoMisure>
```

Comment: Parfait, your code is simply fantastic!!! There's only one thing to change: in the very first row of the output xml the encoding is "UTF-16" but the input file is "UTF-8" witch gives me this parsing error: "Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content". Is there a way to fix it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Simply add `encoding="UTF-8"` in the `<xsl:output>` tag of XSLT. See update.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, i managed to correct it myself adding the required encoding :
 & "   " _

This is the complete code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub XSLTransform() On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    ' ENABLE REFERENCE: Microsoft XML v, #.#
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument, newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim LResult As String

    ' LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
    xmlDoc.async = False
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\XML_Cutter\Input.xml"

    xslDoc.async = False
    xslDoc.LoadXML DynamicXSLT("IT001E04153430")  '<------ PASS SEARCH ITEM

    ' TRANSFORM XML
    xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc

    newDoc.Save "C:\XML_Cutter\Output.xml"

    MsgBox "Successfully transformed XML!", vbInformation
    Exit Sub

ExitHandle:
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Err.Raise xslDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , xslDoc.parseError.reason
    Resume ExitHandle

End Sub

Function DynamicXSLT(searchpod As String) As String
    Dim xslstr As String

    xslstr = " <xsl:stylesheet version=""1.0"" xmlns:xsl=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"">" _
                & "   <xsl:output indent=""yes"" encoding=""UTF-8"" method=""xml"" />" _
                & "   <xsl:strip-space elements=""*""/>" _
                & " " _
                & "   <xsl:param name=""param1""/>" _
                & " " _
                & "   <xsl:template match=""@*|node()"">" _
                & "     <xsl:copy>" _
                & "       <xsl:apply-templates select=""@*|node()""/>" _
                & "     </xsl:copy>" _
                & "   </xsl:template>" _
                & " " _
                & "  <!-- REMOVE ALL OTEHR PODS -->" _
                & "   <xsl:template match=""DatiPod[Pod!='" & searchpod & "']"">" _
                & "   </xsl:template>" _
                & " " _
                & " </xsl:stylesheet>"

    DynamicXSLT = xslstr

End Function
```

Thank you very much Parfait, you've been very kind!

Andrea